# how to add button when I used setcontentpane at once?

Tags: java, forms, swing, debugging, jframe

This code is connecting to mysql and show tables in a JFrame.first of all,I tried `frame.add(table)` and it didn't work but `frame.setcontentpane(table)`
in this code is working and I can see my tables in mysql.

```
form.getContentPane().add(table);
```

is also showing me the empty table and it is not working.

I want to know what is differences between **add** and **setcontentpane**?

why add is not working?

also in GUI I dragged a button and I wanted to show it in my JFrame.but when I have setcontentpane I can't after that,show my button

**I want to have a design frame(right click->New Jframe) like the students JFrame I don't wantto make a class and code my design I want to use GUI builder so dragging my components and use the dragged componnents**

Main.java:

```
     Vector columnNames = new Vector();
     Vector data = new Vector();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school", "colorway", "colorway");
        String sql = "Select name,lname from student";
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
        columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnName(i));
    }

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        Vector row = new Vector(columns);
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
            row.addElement(resultSet.getObject(i));
        }
        data.addElement(row);
    }
    resultSet.close();
    statement.close();
    Students form=new Students();
    JTable  table=new JTable(data, columnNames);
    form.setContentPane(table);
    form.setVisible(true);
```

Students.java:

```
public class Students extends javax.swing.JFrame {
//somecode
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration    

    public JPanel getjpanel(){
        return this.jPanel1;
    }

    public JScrollPane getJscrollPane()
    {
        return this.jScrollPane1;
    }

    public JTable getJTable()
    {
        return this.jTable1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `setContentPane` to add your components.  The `contentPane` is where you should be adding your components instead.  When you do `setContentPane`, you actually replace that container with the component you are trying to `add`.

Add the components using `add`:

```
form.getContentPane().add(table);
```

As by default, the container has a [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), it will add the table in the centre; you can then add a button below by using:

```
form.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Have a look at this article to see [how to change layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), and what different types of layouts exist to position your components as you wish.

Edit: Ok, here is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of a working table to help understand how this works:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public MyFrame () {

        String[] columns = {"one", "two", "three"};
        String[][] data = {
            {"a1", "a2", "a3"},
            {"b1", "b2", "b3"},
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);

        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        getContentPane().add(new JButton("Hello"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                    public void run() { new MyFrame(); }
            });
    }
}
```

Here, the only **trick** I am using is to add the table inside a scroll pane so that the table becomes scrollable when data are filling it, but the layout is just as I described.

**Last Update:**
If you are using the NetBeans GUI builder, then *you shouldn’t have to worry about where the components are being added*, `contentPane` or not: the Visual Editor takes care of it for you – in which case your question `setContentPane` or `add` becomes irrelevant.  If you want to change the layout of your JFrame form, right-click, select `Set Layout` and choose the layout you want.

What I suspect you are trying to do though (but again this is me speculating with the little info I am going with) is to add a new table every time you reload data: you should not be doing this.  You should use a `TableModel` to refresh the content of the table.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't show my table,it is showing my empty table which I designed in GUI

Comment: @nikparsa `add` should work if you use constraints.  Can you provide us with a SSCCE to see exactly what the problem is?

Comment: sorry,I didn't got your point what should I do to elaborate my question?

Comment: @nikparsa From what you are saying and the bit of code you are giving, there is no way of understanding what is going wrong.  If you provide  working example similar to the one I gave, (a) you can narrow down your issue to a small portion of code, and (b) we can straightaway understand what the problem is.

Comment: I didn't code in my Jframe class I am coding in my main.java.can you tell me how I can do it in main.java?

Comment: @nikparsa You shouldn’t be adding components inside the `Main` class, especially if you are using a visual UI builder.  They should be added in your form, i.e. `Students`.

Comment: well how?! you men I should bring whole of my code to students.class? you mean I should add my table in students.class?it is weird then.

Comment: @nikparsa You should add your components to the JFrame form you created with NetBeans — to me it is unclear whether this is the `Main` or the `Students` class.  You should also add your components to the form using the visual editor.

Comment: Sebastian Now I transformed my whole code to the Students class I don't know why it is unclear still I prepared here what was needed,the whole project,I didn't do anything more than this.

Comment: @nikparsa I have updated my answer, and added an example there: https://github.com/tychobrailleur/jtable-example.  HTH.

Comment: what's  Ant 1.8.0? I don't have it,I can't run your project unfortunately

Comment: I saw your whole code and I searched about Ant,it is Apache stuff,I will try to understand your code.Java GUI is really hard C# is like a heaven! in comparison:(

Comment: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/04/12/how-to-install-apache-ant-on-windows/ I used this Link and finally I installed ant sucessfully but again I have errors running your project

Comment: @nikparsa I use NB 7.2 which comes out-of-the-box with Ant 1.8.  If you open the project with NB 7.2, you should not have to install anything else.